# Eigen: fast comparison of `SparseMatrix` sparsity without explicit storage of sparsity pattern

Tags: c++, hash, eigen, eigen3

I have an algorithm which takes `Eigen::SparseMatrix` as input. My algorithm can take advantage of using known sparsity: it analyzes sparsity of input matrix during first call, and than it uses this information for subsequent calls assuming that every input matrix has same sparsity pattern.

But an user of my algorithm can theoretically call it on matrices with different sparsity patterns. I want to check that sparsity of input matrix is the same as sparsity of previous. Obviously i can just store sparsity pattern of input from first call and compare it with sparsity of current input. But i need to avoid storage of previous matrix sparsity due to memory constraints.

Also i cannot just save pointer to CSC structures of matrices because input matrices can be allocated in different places.

Is there a way to do it in `Eigen`? Maybe some hash function for sparsity?

Comment: I would suggest that you give the user the possibility to `computeWithSameSparsityPattern(SparseMatrix const&)` and say it is undefined behavior if the sparsity pattern actually changes. That would be the same behavior as with the sparse solvers and `compute`/`analyzePattern` and `factorize`

Comment: @chtz thank you for answer! Actually this is my current solution.